# ReferenceError: function is not defined when using onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set up an anchor tag using javascript so that that `onclick`, I call a function `showSavingsEasterEgg` and pass it a value. The problem I am getting is that I'm not referencing my function correctly:

`ReferenceError: showSavingsEasterEgg is not defined`

I've tried moving the `showSavingsEasterEgg` function into the `showData` function to see if it solved the scoping problem, but it didn't.

Any tips

```
define(["jquery", "go/util", "underscore", "jqueryui/slider"], function ($, util,_) {

  function showData(data) {
    $('#item').append('<a class="savings_link" href="#" onclick=\'showSavingsEasterEgg('+data[key]['saving']+')\'> Savings');
  }

  function showSavingsEasterEgg(data){
    console.log("SUccess");
    console.log(data);
  }

});
```

Comment: btw `ReferenceError: define is not defined`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the definition of `showSavingsEasterEgg` directly in the global scope.

Here, it can't be found.

You can do this :

```
window.showSavingsEasterEgg = function (data){
    console.log("SUccess");
    console.log(data);
};
define(["jquery", "go/util", "underscore", "jqueryui/slider"], function ($, util,_) {
  function showData(data) {
    $('#item').append('<a class="savings_link" href="#" onclick=\'showSavingsEasterEgg('+data[key]['saving']+')\'> Savings');
  }
});
```

Comment: do you know what is define() here ?

Comment: @eicto no, but that's not the problem : "showSavingsEasterEgg is not defined".

Answer (score 2):

Wondering why nobody suggested the most obvious, convenient and "best practice" way so far. You shouldn't use *inline event handling* at all, do it unobtrusive.

```
$('#item').append($('<a>', {
    'class':    'savings_link',
    href:       '#',
    click:      function(e) {
        console.log("SUccess");
        console.log(data);
    }
}});
```

Comment: I wanted to use onClick because I have several anchor tags with the same ID and if I clicked on one with an event listener, my function gets called several times.

Answer (score 1):

Make showSavingsEasterEgg global. you can call only globally accessible objects/references from html code.

```
 window.showSavingsEasterEgg = function(data){
    console.log("SUccess");
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know and understand what is the definition of `"scope"` in any programming languages. Please move the function named `"showSavingsEasterEgg"` out side of the parent function and it will work like a charm. It's because you defined it as a private member of the parent function.

Cheers